# How do I tokenize a string only using <iostream>?

Tags: c++, iostream, strtok

I want to learn how to tokenize a string, like the strtok function only using `<iostream>`.

I made a program that deletes the spaces but I don't thinks its the same as strtok.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   int i = 0;
   char s[100]="fix the car";
   while(s[i] != '\0'){
       if(s[i] == ' ')
            s[i] = s[i-1];
                else std::cout << s[i];

    i++;
    }
   return 0;
}

prints: fixthecar
```

I want the whole strtok function, not just deleting delimiters, heard I have to use pointers, but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: What do you think "`s[i] == s[i-1];`" does, what is the purpose of this line of code?

Comment: It was supposed to be =, my bad.
Should get rid of the space in this example.
Or
 if (s[i] == 'a')
it should get rid of all the a's in the text.

Comment: Tricky with just <iostream>. Add in <sstream> and you have a lot of string parsing opportunities. If you're expected to write your own `strtok`, how it works [is described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: I know its tricky but for this I want to use iostream only.

Comment: What if the the first character in the string is a space, so this becomes `s[0]=s[-1]`, and since `s[-1]` does not exist, of course, this becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: *I want the whole strtok function, not just deleting delimiters* -- It looks like you started to write a program without a plan in mind.  You are showing us a program that does something completely different than what you were asked to do, and (I guess) hoping a tweak here or there would get it to work.  I don't see that happening without a partial, if not a complete rewrite.

Comment: Only had this specific string in mid. So at the moment the first character can't be a space.
I don't know how to do the function, I thought this is as close as it gets atm.

Answer (score -1):

The internal implementation of `strtok` has already been discussed here, you should check that before opening new questions.

The key to the operation of `strtok()` is preserving the location of the last seperator between seccessive calls (that's why `strtok()` continues to parse the very original string that is passed to it when it is invoked with a `null pointer` in successive calls)..

Have a look at this `strtok()` implementation which has a slightly different functionality than the one provided by `strtok()`

```
char *zStrtok(char *str, const char *delim) {
    static char *static_str=0;      /* var to store last address */
    int index=0, strlength=0;           /* integers for indexes */
    int found = 0;                  /* check if delim is found */

   /* delimiter cannot be NULL
   * if no more char left, return NULL as well
   */
   if (delim==0 || (str == 0 && static_str == 0))
       return 0;

   if (str == 0)
       str = static_str;

   /* get length of string */
   while(str[strlength])
       strlength++;

   /* find the first occurance of delim */
   for (index=0;index<strlength;index++)
       if (str[index]==delim[0]) {
           found=1;
           break;
       }

   /* if delim is not contained in str, return str */
   if (!found) {
       static_str = 0;
       return str;
   }

   /* check for consecutive delimiters
   *if first char is delim, return delim
   */
   if (str[0]==delim[0]) {
       static_str = (str + 1);
       return (char *)delim;
   }

   /* terminate the string
   * this assignmetn requires char[], so str has to
   * be char[] rather than *char
   */
   str[index] = '\0';

   /* save the rest of the string */
   if ((str + index + 1)!=0)
       static_str = (str + index + 1);
   else
       static_str = 0;

       return str;
}
```

Comment: The OP only wants to use `<iostream>`.  I don't see where `<iostream>` functions are used in your answer.